# Basic question about functions and integrals.

Tags: functions

1. Question: I take a coordinate system and draw (with a pencil) any function on a paper. Each $x$ shall only have one $y$. I can draw as much curves as I want. 
   **Are all the arbitrary lines that I can draw describable by a function with $y = f(x) = $......?**
2. Question: Does any continous function $f(x)$ have a related function so that $F'(x)=f(x)$. I mean if I take any continous term for $f(x)$: Does a term for $F(x)$ exist for all continous $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, it's true that if $f$ is continuous, then it has an antiderivative, so such an $F$ must exist.

For the first part, intuitively, I'd think that the probability of you drawing a line that is exactly describable by such a function is 0.

Comment: So, not any continous line with one y for one x is describable by a function.

Comment: Any continuous line with one y for one x is a function... but you won't be able to find a specific rule in the form $y = f(x)$. This rule has to describe an uncountable number of points in finite notation, so it would be quite strange if we could describe a completely random line in a nice way. However, it IS true that a continuous line on a closed interval (for example $0 \le x \le 1$) can be **approximated** by a specific rule.

Comment: Please clarify your answer to the second part. Such an $F$ exists because $f$ is continuous, not merely because it is integrable as one possible reading of your answer seems to suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. F exists because f is integrable. And f is integrable because it is continuous. I think it would be confusing to leave out that implication.

Comment: @Mathmo123, "$F$ exists because $f$ is integrable" --- this is incorrect, not all integrable functions have antiderivatives.

Comment: Right you are. I've clarified it now.